# Windows Event Log, a strange Microsoft Windows Folder appears

Tags: windows, events, logging, applocker

On my colleague's computer these folder appeared in the Windows Event Log. What on earth am I looking at ? Is this functionality of 'AppLocker' or is this just a virus ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IONmq.jpg)

Comment: Explained here: https://superuser.com/questions/1340277/pseudo-english-looking-characters-used-in-windows-10-insider-preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's either a functionality or necessarily a virus.

Maybe your colleague's Operative System was modified.

Non-genuine Operative Systems **might** come with pre-installed malware, depending on where you downloaded it from. Or might become infected (just like any other O.S., genuine or not), depending on what you executed on it.